# Accessing Azure Notification Hub Pricing Tier Via .NET

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I want to determine the current pricing tier of my hub so I can use/not use telemetry functions without generating errors. I have found a PricingTier class, but it states it "Creates a custom value for PricingTier". Does the NotificationHubClient have access to the pricing tier in use?

Comment: Can’t we just look at the pricing setting in the Azure Portal? They want to understand the requirement deeper. Could you please elaborate here.

Comment: Using Azure push notifications, if using the "Standard" pricing tier, GetNotificationOutcomeDetailsAsync returns a details result. It is dependent on receipt of a NotificationID from the NotificationOutcome of the SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync function. Passing a null NotificationID, which is the result if the Standard tier is not in use, into GetNotificationOutcomeDetailsAsync results in an error.

Comment: I have seen a reference which identified sub-tiers to Free, Basic and Standard, which implied a larger variety of resources beyond what we see generally on the portal that might made available and which I would modify code for. Currently, as a developer, MS support suggested I switch between tiers to reduce costs. In order to do so, beyond modifying the portal, I have to modify code as well. I would prefer to code the switch based the tier in use, which the NotificationID doesn't truly represent.